# Formulas in Fox Pro

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am new to Visual Fox Pro so if anybody could help me I would really appreciate it.

How do the formulas below can be written in fox pro,

```
Prev_Pay=-pmt(rate%/12,30*12,Loan)
New_Mod=Sum(Loan*90%)
New_Pay=-pmt(2%/12,30*12,New_Mod)
```

I need to find the value of Prev_Pay, New_Mod and New_Pay fields based on the Loan and Rate.

Comment: What is the intention of Sum(Loan*90%)?  Should New_Mod = Loan * 90%?  I may be missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Check out VFP's Payment() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Loan = 20000
rate = .075
Prev_Pay = -PAYMENT(Loan, rate/12, 30*12)
New_mod = (Loan * .90)
New_Pay = -PAYMENT(New_mod, .02/12, 30*12)
? Prev_Pay
? New_mod
? New_Pay
```

Please see my question regarding the calc of New_mod